# How to set same endpoint for set of S3 buckets on Amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I have following S3 buckets

- "client1"
- "client2"
- ...
- "clientX"

and our clients upload data to their buckets via jar app (client1 to bucket client1 ect.). Here is peace of code:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
File file = new File(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + '/' + fileName);
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, datasource + '/' + fileName, file));
```

and problem is, that they have firewall for output traffic. They must allow URL .amazonaws.com in firewall. Is it possible to set endpoint to our domain storage.domain.com ?

We are expecting, that we will change region in future, but all our client are locket to amazonaws.com = US_EAST_1 region now -> all our clients will need change rules in firewall.

If the endpoint will be storage.domain.com - everything will be ok :)

Example of expected clients URL

- client1 will put data to URL client1.storage.domain.com
- client2 will put data to URL client2.storage.domain.com
- clientX will put data to URL clientX.storage.domain.com

We know about setting in CloudFront, but it's per bucket. We are finding solution with one global AWS setting. How can we do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Part of the answer depends strongly on whether you will be using HTTPS.  It is almost inconceivable that you wouldn't be, but that is a detail that we need to know.  Also, why would the client need to open up your entire domain or an entire subdomain, rather than the client's specific domain?  And, what about clients who whitelist based on IP address, not hostname?

Comment: Yes, we will use HTTPS. We want one endpoint for all our clients - one point for upload - same rule in firewall for all of clients. It's easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be affordable for you (due to extra fee you may have), but this should work:

- Create Route53 with your domain and subdomains (client1, client2.. clientX)
- Create (or use default) VPC with endpoints (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)
- Route all traffic from Route53 to your VPC through the internet gateway (IGW)

You may need to have Security group and NACL things configured. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: There are gaps in this solution.  You can't simply "route all traffic from Route 53 through your Internet Gateway," nor can you access an S3 VPC endpoint through an Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous factors at play, here, not the least of which is support for SSL.

First, we need to eliminate one obvious option that will **not** work:

S3 supports naming each bucket after a domain name, then using a CNAME to point at each bucket.  So, for example, if you name a bucket client-1.storage.example.com and then point a DNS CNAME (in Route 53) for `client-1.storage.example.com CNAME client-1.storage.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com` then this bucket becomes accessible on the Internet as `client-1.storage.example.com`.

This works only if you do not try to use HTTPS.  The reason for the limitation is a combination of factors, which are outside the scope of this answer.  There is no workaround that uses only S3.  Workarounds require additonal components.

Even though the scenario above will not work for your application, let's assume for a moment that it will, since it makes another problem easy to illustrate:

> We are finding solution with one global AWS setting

This may not be a good idea, even if it is possible.  In the above scenario, it would be tempting for you to set up a wildcard CNAME so that `*.storage.example.com CNAME s3[-region].amazonaws.com` which would give you a magical DNS entry that would work for any bucket with a name matching `*.storage.example.com` and created in the appropriate region... but there is a serious vulnerability in such a configuration -- I could create a bucket called `sqlbot.storage.example.com` (assuming no such bucket already existed) and now I have a bucket that you do not control, using a hostname under your domain, and you don't have any way to know about it, or stop it.  I can potentially use this to breach your clients' security because now my bucket is accessible from inside your client's firewall, thanks to the wildcard configuration.

No, you really need to automate the steps to deploy each client, regardless of the ultimate solution, rather than relying on a single global setting.  All AWS services (S3, Route 53, etc.) lend themselves to automation.

CloudFront *seems like* it holds the key to the simplest solution, by allowing you to map each client hostname to their own bucket.  Yes, this does require a CloudFront distribution to be configured for each client, but this operation can also be automated, and there isn't a charge for each CloudFront distribution.  The only charges for CloudFront are usage-related (per request and per GB transferted).  Additional advantages here include SSL support (including wildcard `*.storage.example.com` certificate from ACM which can be shared across multiple CloudFront distributions) and the fact that with CloudFront in the path, you do not need the bucket name and the hostname to be the same.

This also gives you the advantage of being able to place each bucket in the most desirable region for that specific bucket.  It is, however, limited to files not exceeding 20 GB in size, due to the size limit imposed by CloudFront.

But the problem with using CloudFront for applications with a large number of uploads of course is that you're going to pay bandwidth charges for the uploads.  In Europe, Canada, and the US, it's cheap ($0.02/GB) but in India it is much more expensive ($0.16/GB), with other areas varying in price between these extremes.  (You pay for downloads with CloudFront, too, but in that case, S3 does not bill you for any bandwidth charges when downloads are pulled through CloudFront... so the consideration is not usually as significant, and adding CloudFront in front of S3 for downloads can actually be slightly cheaper than using S3 alone).

So, while CloudFront is probably the official answer, there are a couple of considerations that are still potentially problematic.

S3 transfer acceleration avoids the other problem you mentioned -- the bucket regions.  Buckets with transfer acceleration enabled are accessible at `https://bucket-name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com` regardless of the bucket region, so that's a smaller hole to open, but the transfer acceleration feature is only supported for buckets without dots in their bucket names.  And transfer acceleration comes with additional bandwidth charges.

So where does this leave you?

There's not a built-in, "serverless" solution that I can see that would be simple, global, automatic, and inexpensive.

It seems unlikely, in my experience, that a client who is so security-conscious as to restrict web access by domain would simultaneously be willing to whitelist what is in effect a wildcard (*.storage.example.com) and could result in trusting traffic that should not be trusted.  Granted, it would be better than `*.amazonaws.com` but it's not clear just how much better.

I'm also reasonably confident that many security configurations rely on static IP address whitelisting, rather than whitelisting by name... filtering by name in an HTTPS environment has implications and complications of its own.

Faced with such a scenario, my solution would revolve around proxy servers deployed in EC2 -- in the same region as the buckets -- which would translate the hostnames in the requests into bucket names and forward the requests to S3.  These could be deployed behind ELB or could be deployed on Elastic IP addresses, load balanced using DNS from Route 53, so that you have static endpoint IP addresses for clients that need them.

Note also that any scenario involving `Host:` header rewrites for requests authorized by AWS Signature V4 will mean that you have to modify your application's code to sign the requests with the real hostname of the target S3 endpoint, while sending the requests to a different hostname.  Sending requests directly to the bucket endpoint (including the transfer acceleration endpoint) is the only way to avoid this.